# Select second minimum value in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like the following, and originally I wanted to return the earliest update date for different statuses.
However, since the project was cancelled and recreated, I want to ignore the first planning date and only return the second planning date.

```
+------------+------------+------------+-----------+
| Project ID |  UpdateDT  |  Audit ID  | SubStatus |
+------------+------------+------------+-----------+
|   11111    | 2017-12-20 |   10123    | Planning  |
|   11111    | 2017-05-25 |   10135    | Planning  |
|   11111    | 2017-10-11 |   10254    | Cancelled |
+------------+------------+------------+-----------+
```

My query is like the following, but it can only return the earliest planning date rather the second earliest one. I added a CASE expression but the result is still the same. Can anyone please shed some lights? Thank you.

```
SELECT DISTINCT sub.Request_ID
    ,sub.UpdateDT
    ,a.reqStatus
FROM [RptChange].[dbo].[tRequestsAudit] a
JOIN (
    SELECT [reqID] [Request_ID]
        ,CASE 
            WHEN [reqStatus] IN ('Cancelled')
                THEN MAX([reqUpdateDt])
            ELSE MIN([reqUpdateDt])
            END AS [UpdateDT]
        ,MIN([AuditID]) AS EarliestAuditID
        ,[reqStatus] SubStatus
    FROM [RptChange].[dbo].[tRequestsAudit]
    WHERE [reqID] = 11111
    GROUP BY [reqStatus]
        ,[reqID]
    ) sub ON sub.[EarliestAuditID] = a.AuditID
```

```
+------------+------------+------------+-----------+
| Project ID |  UpdateDT  |  Audit ID  | SubStatus |
+------------+------------+------------+-----------+
|   11111    | 2017-05-25 |   10135    | Planning  |
|   11111    | 2017-10-11 |   10254    | Cancelled |
+------------+------------+------------+-----------+
```

The result I want:

```
+------------+------------+------------+-----------+
| Project ID |  UpdateDT  |  Audit ID  | SubStatus |
+------------+------------+------------+-----------+
|   11111    | 2017-12-20 |   10123    | Planning  |
|   11111    | 2017-10-11 |   10254    | Cancelled |
+------------+------------+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: What if there are 3 planning dates, do you want the third or the second?

Comment: Also what if there are several records in Cancelled status? Do you want to display them all, or pick one of them only?

Comment: @GMB If there are multiple records in planning status, I will pick the earliest one but it has to be after cancelled status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to tackle this using ROW_NUMBER.

```
declare @tRequestsAudit table
(
    ProjectID int
    , UpdateDT date
    , AuditID int
    , SubStatus varchar(10)
)

insert @tRequestsAudit values
(11111, '2017-12-20', 10123, 'Planning')
, (11111, '2017-05-25', 10135, 'Planning')
, (11111, '2017-10-11', 10254, 'Cancelled')
;

select ProjectID
    , UpdateDT
    , AuditID
    , SubStatus
from
(
    select *
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by ProjectID, SubStatus order by UpdateDT desc)
    from @tRequestsAudit
) x
where x.SubStatus <> 'Planning'
OR
(
    x.SubStatus = 'Planning'
    AND
    x.RowNum = 2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL 2012 and above, you can use the lead function to remove the Planning records which were cancelled later. This query assumes that there is going to be a sequential order of Planning and Cancelling:

```
select a.*
from
(select *,lead(Substatus,1) Over(Partition by [Project ID] Order by UpdateDt) as lead_status
from [RptChange].[dbo].[tRequestsAudit])a
where a.lead_status!='Cancelled'
```